# Get javascript object from ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I create a javascript object from an AJAX response?

This is what I'm currently doing:

PHP:

```
<?
echo '{status:"1", site:"example.com"}';
?>
```

JS:

```
success:function(data_response){
    var object = eval( data_response );
    console.log(object.url);
    }});
```

I'm currently getting "undefined" on the console. How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try something like this:

PHP

```
<?
echo json_encode(array("status"=>1,"site"=>"example.com"));
?>
```

Ajax call here with your params in JS

```
$.ajax({
  url: url, // your url where the php is
  dataType: 'json', 
  data: data, //send data
//callback
  success: function(data_response){  
      alert(data_response.status);
      alert(data_response.site);
}
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Set the `dataType` of the ajax request to `json`, and the `data_response` will be an object already parsed to.

Or you could use `$.getJSON` also.

Answer (score 1):

instead of making your own json notation use php built in `json_encode`

```
<?php
    return json_encode(array('status' => '1', 'site' => 'example.com'));
?>
```

Also you're logging `object.url` but it should be `object.site`.

You may also need to set your header to return `application/json` instead of `text/html`.  This can be done also by specifying the `dataType` type parameter in your AJAX request to `json`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse a raw object string using `eval`, you must wrap the object notation code in parens:

```
var object = eval( '(' + data_response + ')' );
```

The following will choke the parser:

```
eval('{status:"1", site:"example.com"}')
```

But this will work as you expect:

```
eval('({status:"1", site:"example.com"})')
```

**Edit:** Please note, I don't necessarily endorse this solution.  This is just so you understand what's needed *if* you're going to use `eval`.